# The action 'complete' could not be found for ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I have this error :

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /complete
>
> The action 'complete' could not be found for ApplicationController

I think I set the **routes.rb** correctly :

```
get    :complete,                to: 'application#complete'
```

And this is my **application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 def complete
   ...
 end
end
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: A actually tried your syntax (from the question) on rails 4.2.7.1 app and it worked.

Comment: Do you think it could come from an other file (models, ...) ? I'm on Rails 5

Comment: Can you try ApplicationController.new.respond_to?(:complete) from console?

Comment: This return false. I tried with an other action in this same controller, and it return true. So the problem really looks to come from the action complete

Comment: I tried it on rails 5 and it worked too, can you provide your ApplicationController code?

Comment: issue fixed ! The action was in protected... This is the problem with cleaning the code before publishing it on stack :( Thanks for your help, You make me find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct, Try to update **routes.rb** with below line of code.

```
get '/complete', to: 'application#complete', as: :complete
```

OR

```
match '/complete', to: 'application#complete', as: :complete
```

OR

```
get :complete, controller:"application"
```

> If all of above doesn't work may be you have declared `complete`
>   method `private or protected`. Making it public will solve the issue.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, still the same error with the three syntaxes :s

Comment: i have updated my answer, You can accept it so that it helps other if they are facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `complete` method is cannot access from outside, have any private or protected keywords above this `complete` method definition. To surely this method can be access from outside, add public keyword at above.

```
public
def complete
   ...
end
```

Sorry about my bad English.